# while iterating if statement wont evaluate

Tags: python, csv

this little snippet of code is my attempt to pull multiple unique values out of rows in a CSV. the CSV looks something like this in the header:

descr1, fee part1, fee part2, descr2, fee part1, fee part2,

with the descr columns having many unique names in a single column. I want to take these unique fee names and make a new header out of them. to do this I decided to start by getting all the different descr columns names, so that when I start pulling data from the actual rows I can check to see if that row has a fee amount or one of the fee names I need. There are probably a lot of things wrong with this code, but I am a beginner. I really just want to know why my first if statement is never triggered when the l in fin does equal a comma, I know it must at some point as it writes a comma to my row string. thanks!

```
row = ''
header = ''
columnames = ''
cc = ''
#fout = open(","w")
fin = open ("raw data.csv","rb")

for l in fin:
    if ',' == l:
        if 'start of cust data' not in row:
            if 'descr' in row:
                columnames = columnames + ' ' + row
                row = ''
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
    else:
        row = row+l
        print(columnames)

print(columnames)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you iterate over a file, you get lines, not characters -- and they have the newline character, `\n`, at the end. Your `if ',' == l:` statement will never succeed because even if you had a line with only a single comma in it, the value of `l` would be `",\n"`.

I suggest using the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html): you'll get much better results than trying to do this by hand like you're doing.

Comment: I didn't know that the CSV module existed, I will use that. thank you for clearing up my misunderstanding on how iterating happens.